# Form handling and validation with vuex best practice

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex

I have a big form (10+ inputs) which values I want to bind (like v-model) with object I have in vuex store, on submission it needs to send axios request to server (server will handle validation) and respond with error object (this field is required, this value is too short, etc...).

I will provide minimalistic example with just one input field.
Object student is for student itself obviously, and error object will be there to handle errors from server response.

App.vue

```
<template>
 <div>

  <input v-model="student.name">
  <span>{{error.name}}</span>

 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

 export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
   student.name: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.student.name
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('setStudentName', value)
    }
   },
   error.name: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.error.name
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('setErrorName', value)
    }
   }

  }
 }
</script>
```

and this is mu vuex store:

```
export default {
 state: {
  student: { name: ''},
  error: { name: ''}
 },
 mutations: {
  setStudentName: (state, student.name) => (state.student.name = student.name),
  setErrorName: (state, error.name) => (state.error.name = error.name)
 }

}
```

So this works perfectly, but imagine having 10+ inputs and having to write setters and getters for 10 inputs x 2 objects (student and error), that is like 40 setters&getters at least.

Is there a easier way to do this?

I have also tried **vuex-forms**  which is great, but package is incomplete and documentation is missing, tried **vuex-map-fields**, which is good only for handling one object at the time.

All suggestions are welcome, what it the correct way to do this?

Comment: Create reusable component with props: 1. property, 2. mutation to call.

Comment: if i'm going with props, I would stick to the vue without vuex, I just wanna do this in the correct way.

Comment: 1. Why do you want to use Vuex with this? 2. Why do you think going with a reusable component is not the correct way?

Comment: this is just a "minimal reproducible example", true story is that lot of data that is binded to this form needs to be accessed from multiple components throughout the app, so doing it with props is not a solution in this case

Comment: It's still better solution then doing 10 or more computed bindings, and it is a correct way to do. Vue is a component based framework 
I'm suggesting creating a renderless component that gives you the binded computed properties based on received props. 

Other option (if you don't like the first one ) is to create, a loop to make a computed properties for every input you need. But I don't think it's a cleaner way.

Comment: well yes, I thought about that as well (to create a loop), but I wanted to check with community what is the "correct" way to do it. But honestly, since Vue is relatively new I think that there is no "correct" way to do it and that it is up to developer to come up with creative solution for his specific needs.

Comment: Well to me it is always about developers choice. If you make a decision about implementation, if you can describe the pros and cons and stand your "ground" behind that decision (sometimes convincing other developers) then it is a correct way to do stuff  Anyway good luck!